# How can I use the puppeteer devtools protocol to find all media queries that did not match the current element?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I want to use the puppeteer devtools protocol to do the following, given an element (i.e., its `nodeId`), I would like to know what media queries did not apply to the current element, but could have (e.g if it was larger/smaller/etc.)

Comment: The easiest way to do this would probably be by executing some JS to read the [CSSRuleList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRuleList). Then check if the rule is a media query, then check if the selectors within the media query match your element. Things might get complicated to accurately reflect the cascading nature of CSS.